# Invalid date in IE11 even though date format is ISO 8601 supported

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I have used moment to convert date to ISO supported format as it's working fine on chrome & firefox but not on IE11 so 
I as per the docs YYYY-MM-DD is supported iso format,
here my js_time1 format is as mentioned ddd MMM D YYYY hh:mm:ss
so i have used this to fomrat it

```
var js_time = moment(js_time1).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

i have also tried 
 `var js_time = moment(js_time1,'ddd MMM D YYYY hh:mm:ss').format('YYYY-MM-DD');`
 but no use.
Format for js_time1 is Mon Aug 3rd 2018 12:12:21
Thanks in advance

Comment: Show us the actual content of `js_time1`. But the answer is almost certainly: Use a format string when doing the parsing: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i have added the format. Isn't the 2nd attempt of mine is the same thing what you have suggested

Comment: This might not be the cause, but please note that IE 11 does not support `input type=date` and automatically changes the element's type property to `text`.

Comment: @ParthGoswami - Possibly. Again: Show is the actual contents of `js_time1`. You've put "Format for..." at the end, but is that exactly what's in it? (Notice that `D` doesn't match `3rd`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `js_time1` is what you've shown as "format for" (`"Mon Aug 3rd 2018 12:12:21"`), there are three problems:

- August 3rd, 2018 was a Friday, not a Monday.
- Your parsing format uses `D` for `3rd`. `D` doesn't match ordinals, that's `Do`.
- You're using `hh` (1-12) for hours, which is meant to be used with `a`. I assume your time is in 24-hour format, so that's `HH`.

It works if you fix those things (including fixing the error in the string):

```js
var js_time1 = "Fri Aug 3rd 2018 12:12:21";
var js_time = moment(js_time1,'ddd MMM Do YYYY HH:mm:ss').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
console.log(js_time);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```